# Extracting string value before bracket using regexp in Athena

Tags: sql, amazon-athena, presto, trino

I am trying to learn about regexp and I am trying to extract data that is before open bracket character using regexp_extract.

**String value:**

| device |
| --- |
| iphone-ios-cx 12.45.0(2144) |

**Expected output:**

| device |
| --- |
| iphone-ios-cx 12.45.0 |

I am able to achieve this using split_part function.

```
select split_part(device, '(', 1)
FROM devices_tbl
```

I tried the same using regexp_replace and regexp_extract, both seem to give me incorrect results

```
select regexp_replace(device, '\\(.*\\)','')
FROM devices_tbl
```

How can I achieve the same using regex functions in Athena?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got parenthesis escaping wrong, use single `\`:

```sql
select regexp_replace('iphone-ios-cx 12.45.0(2144)', '\(.*\)','');
```

Output:

```
         _col0         
-----------------------
 iphone-ios-cx 12.45.0
```